# NodeJS Sequelize: Association with alias [alias] does not exist on [model]

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js, associations

i'm using NodeJS & Sequelize for a school project and  i'm struggling on making associations w/ sequelize work. I tried a couple of things before but nothing that made my day.

Basically the thing is that a user can have several playlists (hasMany).
And a playlist belongs to a user (belongsTo).

My error is:
**Association with alias "playlist" does not exist on users**

Here are my models:

```
/* USER MODEL */
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const { db } = require('../utils/db');

const User = db.define('users', {
  id: {
    allowNull: false,
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true,
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
  },
  userID: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
    field: 'user_id',
  },
  firstName: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    field: 'first_name',
    allowNull: false,
  },
}, {
  underscored: true,
  tableName: 'users',
  freezeTableName: true, // Model tableName will be the same as the model name
});

module.exports = {
  User,
};
```

```
/* PLAYLIST MODEL */

const sequelize = require('sequelize');
const { db } = require('../utils/db');

const Playlist = db.define('playlist', {
  id: {
    allowNull: false,
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true,
    type: sequelize.INTEGER,
  },
  name: {
    type: sequelize.STRING,
    field: 'name',
    allowNull: false,
  },
  coverUrl: {
    type: sequelize.STRING,
    field: 'cover_url',
    allowNull: true,
  },
  ownerId: {
    type: sequelize.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
    references: {
      model: 'users',
      key: 'user_id',
    },
  },
}, {
  underscored: true,
  tableName: 'playlist',
  freezeTableName: true,
});

module.exports = {
  Playlist,
};
```

Here is how i load my models:

```
const { Credentials } = require('./credentials');
const { User } = require('./users');
const { Playlist } = require('./playlist');

function loadModels() {
  User.associate = (models) => {
    User.hasMany(models.Playlist, { as: 'playlist' });
  };

  Playlist.associate = (models) => {
    Playlist.belongsTo(models.User, { foreignKey: 'owner_id', as: 'owner' });
  };

  Credentials.sync({ force: false });
  User.sync({ force: false });
  Playlist.sync({ force: false });
}

module.exports = {
  loadModels,
};
```

And finally here is my query where i get this error:

```
const express = require('express');
const { auth } = require('../../middlewares/auth');
const { Playlist } = require('../../models/playlist');
const { User } = require('../../models/users');

const router = express.Router();

router.get('/playlist', [], auth, (req, res) => {
  User.findOne({
    where: { userID: req.user.user_id }, include: 'playlist',
  }).then((r) => {
    console.log(r);
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

I'm trying to get all the playlist that belongs to a user.

I removed all the useless code (jwt check etc..)
So when i'm doing a get request on /playlist I get:
**Unhandled rejection Error: Association with alias "playlist" does not exist on users**.

I understand the error but don't understand why i get this.
What did I miss, any ideas ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally fixed it by re-make all my models and definitions with migrations.
I had the same problem and the solution was that Sequelize pluralize the models name so in my case "playlist" does not exist on users because Sequelize pluralized my model so I had to put "Playlists" instead.

Comment: Hi friend. How did you realize that? I saw your answer and it worked for me, I have a model called Payments (plural), and it showed me the same error as you, when I saw your answer I tried placing Payment (singular) and it worked, but I don't understand why. check my database and the table is called Payments (plural), does it have something to do with associations or what? I really don't understand anything, would you be so kind as to explain me?

Comment: @JulianProg Hi mate, I realized it by reading the doc and trying things. Hard to tell what the problem is for you without seeing your models and migrations file. But basically be aware that when you have a hasMany association, you need to pluralize the model associated. For example, if I take the same code as I wrote up there, I have two models: User and Playlist. My User model has a hasMany association with Playlist model. But because I used hasMany, I had to pluralize Playlist so I had to write this:
User.hasMany(models.Playlists, { foreignKey: 'user_id' }); // models.Playlists (pluralized)

Comment: If I had made a hasOne association instead of a hasMany association I would had to write model.Playlist instead of model.Playlists. Hope it will help